# How to write an inline array of protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I use Google's ProtoBuf and I set lots of value like the following:

```
optional string  force_sampling  = 1;
optional string  status          = 2;
optional string  host            = 3;
optional string  server_addr     = 4;
optional string  server_port     = 5;
optional string  client_addr     = 6;
optional string  request         = 7;
optional string  msec            = 8;
optional string  request_time    = 9;
optional string  logid           = 10;
optional string  request_body    = 11;
optional string  response_body   = 12;
optional string  other           = 100;
```

So, when I set a value to a message, I write many constructions like the following:

```
set_logid(); set_request_body(); set_other(); set_request_body(); etc.
```

Can I have an easier way for doing that?
For example, something like:

```
array way={"set_logid","set_other"}
for (;i = 0;i < len)
{
  sample.way[i]()
}
```

By the way, `set_logid` is inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Message::GetReflection()` function and use it to access the fields by name given in a string.

The documentation is here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection

However, this will turn out to be slower and more complex, so it might not be worth it.